# How to make a button execute its command without clicking it?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have made a tic-tac-toe program for a project at school. I created a random function, which randomizes any number to 8. I had 9 buttons, each for the O's(which is the player) and the X's(which is the computer).

What I want to happen is that if the player clicks the first button, then the random function(named comesy, short for "easy computer") will randomize any number from 8, and configure or click a button related to its number. For example, if I click on button 1, which is the top left button, than comedy might randomize 2 than it will click button 2, which is the top middle button. Basically like an AI.

I tried to add an extra variable equal to zero, which is inside the function for button1. The variable will be added to one when the function for button 1 is executed. I made an if statement that would state that if that variable equals to one than make comesy choose a number, and randomly click a button except for button 1.

This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import font

window = Tk()
window.geometry("750x500")
window.title("Tic Tac Toe")
butn = 0
butn2 = 0
butn3 = 0
#These will be the images
blnk = PhotoImage(file="blank.png")
lbl = Label(text="")
#Easy random
def btn1():
    global butn
    button1.configure(text="O")
    button1.configure(state="disabled")
    butn+=1
def btn2():
    global butn2
    button2.configure(text="O")
    button2.configure(state="disabled")
    butn2=2
def btn3():
    global butn3
    button3.configure(text="O")
    button3.configure(state="disabled")
    butn3=3
def btn4():
    button4.configure(text="O")
    button4.configure(state="disabled")

def btn5():
    button5.configure(text="O")
    button5.configure(state="disabled")

def btn6():
    button6.configure(text="O")
    button6.configure(state="disabled")

def btn7():
    button7.configure(text="O")
    button7.configure(state="disabled")

def btn8():
    button8.configure(text="O")
    button8.configure(state="disabled")

def btn9():
    button9.configure(text="O")
    button9.configure(state="disabled")

#These well be the def functions
def exits():
    window.destroy()

#This is the restart function
def restart():
    lbl.configure(text="Please choose one", font=("Times New Roman 5 bold",15))
    f = font.Font(lbl, lbl.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline=True)
    lbl.configure(font=f)
    hrd.configure(state='normal')
    mdm.configure(state='normal')
    esy.configure(state='normal')
    twply.configure(state='normal')
    button1.configure(text="")
    button1.configure(state='normal')
    button2.configure(text="")
    button2.configure(state='normal')
    button3.configure(text="")
    button3.configure(state='normal')
    button4.configure(text="")
    button4.configure(state='normal')
    button5.configure(text="")
    button5.configure(state='normal')
    button6.configure(text="")
    button6.configure(state='normal')
    button7.configure(text="")
    button7.configure(state='normal')
    button8.configure(text="")
    button8.configure(state='normal')
    button9.configure(text="")
    button9.configure(state='normal')
    window.mainloop()

#This is the two player function
def twoPlay():
    lbl.configure(text="You chose Two Player!")
    mdm.configure(state='disabled')
    esy.configure(state='disabled')
    hrd.configure(state='disabled')
    lbl.place_configure(x=150, y=9)
    window.mainloop()

#This is the medium function
def medium():
    lbl.configure(text="You chose Medium!")
    lbl.place_configure(x=180,y=9)
    hrd.configure(state='disabled')
    esy.configure(state='disabled')
    twply.configure(state='disabled')
    window.mainloop()

#This is the easy function
def easy():
    lbl.configure(text="You chose Easy!")
    lbl.place_configure(x=180,y=9)
    mdm.configure(state='disabled')
    hrd.configure(state='disabled')
    twply.configure(state='disabled')
    window.mainloop()

#This is the hard function
def hard():
    lbl.configure(text="You chose Hard!")
    lbl.place_configure(x=180,y=9)
    mdm.configure(state='disabled')
    esy.configure(state='disabled')
    twply.configure(state='disabled')
    window.mainloop()

#These are the buttons in the tic tac toe
button1 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn1)
button1.place(x=100,y=95)
button2 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn2)
button2.place(x=200,y=95)
button3 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn3)
button3.place(x=300,y=95)
button4 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn4)
button4.place(x=100,y=200)
button5 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn5)
button5.place(x=200,y=200)
button6 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn6)
button6.place(x=300,y=200)
button7 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn7)
button7.place(x=100,y=305)
button8 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn8)
button8.place(x=200,y=305)
button9 = Button(window,text="",width=14,height=7,command=btn9)
button9.place(x=300,y=305)

#These are the play mode buttons
hrd = Button(window, text="Hard",width=7,height=1,command=hard)
hrd.place(x=100,y=40)
mdm = Button(window,text="Medium",width=7,height=1,command=medium)
mdm.place(x=180,y=40)
esy = Button(window,text="Easy",width=7,height=1,command=easy)
esy.place(x=260,y=40)
twply = Button(window,text="2 Player",width=7,height=1,command=twoPlay)
twply.place(x=340,y=40)

#Restart and exit button
rst = Button(window, text="Restart",width=7,height=1,command=restart)
rst.place(x=424,y=385)
ext = Button(window, text="Exit", width=7,height=1,command=exits)
ext.place(x=490,y=385)
#This is going to be the label thats above the mode btns
lbl = Label(window,text="Please choose one", font=("Times New Roman 5 bold",15))
lbl.place(x=180,y=9)
f = font.Font(lbl, lbl.cget("font"))
f.configure(underline=True)
lbl.configure(font=f)

#Easy random
comesy = random.randrange(8)
if button1==btn1 and butn==1:
    print("Button 1 clicked")
    if comesy==1:
        button2.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==2:
        button3.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==3:
        button4.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==4:
        button5.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==5:
        button6.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==6:
        button7.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==7:
        button8.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
    elif comesy==8:
        button9.configure(text="X")
        comesy = random.randrange(8)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You’ve already specified the function to run when each button is clicked.  So… call the one you want to have happen?

Comment: button functions are no different from any other functions. You can call them whenever you want.

Comment: alright but if, I, for example, wanted  to add an if statement, inside the function for button1, the if statement would state that if button 4 is equal to the function it was assigned too or in other words if it was clicked after button1 was clicked, then click button7, but it wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Anonymous If you want to do different actions on different buttons write different functions and merge the common parts. That will keep your code cleaner in the long run.

Comment: @Anonymous I think you need to clarify the question you are asking as it isn't clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Anonymous: A bit offtopic - in the interest of preserving your sanity, you might want to learn about returning functions as a result of other functions (higher-order functions) for the btnN()s instead of copy-pasting the same code over and over and mucking about with globals.